# Ionic cordova app says plugin not installed even after installed

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am using onesignal-cordova-plugin in my ionic project. I have followed the documentation and added the plugin.

```
ionic cordova plugin add onesignal-cordova-plugin
npm install @ionic-native/onesignal
```

But once I build , the app log says

```
Native: tried calling OneSignal.startInit, but the OneSignal plugin is not installed.
```

I have tried removing android and readding but doesnt work. plugin list do show onesignal.

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.13.1 (/home/raj/.nvm/versions/node/v12.2.0/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.6.6
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1102.12
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 11.2.12
   @angular/cli                  : 11.2.12
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 3.1.1

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : android 9.1.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 7 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.15.3
   native-run  : 1.3.0

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/home/raj/android/android-sdk-linux/)
   NodeJS            : v12.2.0 (/home/raj/.nvm/versions/node/v12.2.0/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.14.9
   OS                : Linux 4.4
```

Comment: What version of the plugin you are using?

Answer (score 1):

As per New Onesignal Version Update (3.0+):
startInit method is removed , use setAppId instead.

Eg. window["plugins"].OneSignal.setAppId(environment.OnesignalAppId);

Check your Onesignal Version :
There are lots of api changes in 3.0+
(migration guide : https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/step-by-step-cordova-2x-to-300-upgrade-guide)

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the plugin was not installed with the command below:

```
cordova plugin ls
```

or

```
cordova plugin list
```

A possible solution can be solved with the command below:

```
ionic repair
```

Answer (score 0):

`@ionic-native/onesignal` doesn't work with the latest OneSignal SDK (and Cordova plugin). From 3.0.0, there are breaking changes and the methods defined in this wrapper no longer work.

These changes are documented in the API, and there are a lot of deprecated methods and changes required:
https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/40-api-android-native

The official docs show the use of the new methods for proper setup:
https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ionic-sdk-setup

Answer (score 0):

Try Doing this:

```
$ ionic cordova plugin rm <plugin name>
$ npm uninstall --save <npm-of-plugin>

$ ionic cordova plugin add <plugin name>
$ npm install --save <npm-of-plugin>
```

- add the plugin to app-module.ts providers.
- finally use your plugin when the platform is ready

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
   // call your plugin
});
```